# compare with a 6-byte long string of zeros

Tags: c, string

in my code I work with Ethernet MAC addresses and need to compare for a 00:00:00:00:00:00 address; the easiest solution I came up with is this:

```
#define ETH_ADDR_LEN  6
unsigned char mac[ETH_ADDR_LEN] = { 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6 };  /* example */
const unsigned char empty[ETH_ADDR_LEN] = { 0, };

if (memcmp(mac, empty, ETH_ADDR_LEN) == 0) {
  ....
}
```

Is there a more concise way to achieve my goal?
Simply memcmp(mac, "", 6) won't work -- may I know why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `memcmp(mac, "\0\0\0\0\0", 6)` "works" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`memcmp(mac, "", 6)` does not work because `""` is an array of 1 character with zero value (and decays to a pointer to its single element).

Access to elements outside the array invoke Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The `memcmp(mac, "", 6)` does not work because the empty string consists of a single NUL character. Comparing 6 bytes will compare your MAC address against that NUL plus 5 bytes of potential garbage following it.

You can, however, force your string to contain six NUL characters using the following. Note that it only needs 5 explicit NULs because the string has an additional trailing NUL:

```
if(memcmp(mac, "\0\0\0\0\0", 6) == 0) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: EDIT: Sorry, my web browser is acting up in funny ways. Just ignore my comment.

Comment: No problem, thanks. I have edited my answer to better reflect your clarifications. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks everybody for feedback. I don't completely understand when Scott said that "You can, however, force your string to contain six NUL characters using the following. Note that it only needs 5 explicit NULs because the string has an additional trailing NUL".

Comment: Hi @Mark. This is true of any string literal in C. If I were to type this: `strcmp(s1, "abc", 3)`, then the memory storage for the string "abc" actually has a NUL character following it. In this case, we have the string literal "\0\0\0\0\0", which has 5 explicit NUL characters. But in storage the compiler will have added an additional terminating NUL character just like it did for the string literal "abc".

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your code. Keep it as it is. The "empty" array contains 6 zeroes so it will work just fine.